# Как устанавливаются новые команды в командные строки

Tags: java, cmd, установка, скрипт

Вопрос применительно к Java JRE. После установки  мы можем использовать в командных строках такие команды как `javac`, `java` и др. устанавливаемые команды. Вопрос как именно происходит установка этих команд в cmd (к примеру), или командные строки других ОС. Это какие то скрипты? Где они лежат, какая хронология установки и любые другие тонкости на ваше усмотрение. Вопрос задается в контексте подготовки к техническому собеседованию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с Windows, команды javac, java и др. Это exe программы, путь к которым прописывается в системную переменную Path. Поэтому когда вы в CMD набираете имя, система пробегается по переменным и ищет есть ли такие программы. В переменную Path вы можете и свои программы прописать. Мне кажется такое не спрашивают на собеседованиях, но могу конечно ошибаться.

Comment: Добавлю, что касательно большинства других ОС происходит то же самое. Любые команды (кроме нескольких встроенных в сам shell) ищутся в виде выполнимых файлов в папках, указанных в  переменной окружения PATH. И первый же найденный файл запускается

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь

> `JAVA_HOME` — это переменная среды операционной системы (ОС), которую можно при желании установить после установки Java Development Kit (JDK) или Java Runtime Environment (JRE).  Переменная среды `JAVA_HOME` указывает на расположение в файловой системе, где был установлен JDK или JRE.

это нужно для того чтобы потом использовать эту переменную в скриптах, для запуска нужной версии Java. Если в системе установлено несколько версий, то можно изменить значение переменной среды во время выполнения.

> Эта переменная может быть быть настроена во всех ОС с установленной Java, включая Windows, Ubuntu, Linux, Mac и Android.
>
> Переменная среды `JAVA_HOME` фактически не используется локально установленной средой выполнения Java.  Вместо этого другие программы, установленные на настольном компьютере, которым требуется среда выполнения Java, будут запрашивать у ОС переменную `JAVA_HOME`, чтобы узнать, где установлена ​​среда выполнения.  После того, как расположение установки JDK или JRE найдено, эти программы могут инициировать процессы на основе Java, запускать виртуальные машины Java и использовать утилиты командной строки, такие как архивная утилита Java (jar) или компилятор Java (javac), которые упакованы в пакет установки Java.  каталог `\bin`.

Ещё используется переменная среды `PATH` для того чтобы указать где находятся выполняемые программы.

> Большое различие между параметрами `PATH` и `JAVA_HOME` заключается в том, что первый указывает на каталог bin JDK, а последний указывает на каталог установки.  Разработчики печально известны тем, что смешивают эти два параметра, что неизменно приводит к проблемам с запуском программы и последующим сообщениям об ошибках `JAVA_HOME,` таким как `"JAVA_HOME установлен в недопустимый каталог"` или `"переменная среды JAVA_HOME не установлена"`.
>
> Переменные среды `JAVA_HOME` и `PATH` служат двум совершенно разным целям.  `JAVA_HOME` просто указывает, где установлена ​​Java.  Если вы добавите что-то в переменную `PATH`, это сделает ее доступной для всей операционной системы.  Конечно, многие разработчики, устанавливающие Java, на самом деле хотят, чтобы среда выполнения была общедоступной, поэтому они одновременно устанавливают переменные среды `JAVA_HOME` и `PATH`.

Для того чтобы использовать программы из установленного пакета JRE/JDK достаточно просто использовать переменную окружения `JAVA_HOME` в скрипте. Например в cmd  скриптах используется `%` для извлечения значения переменных среды.

> Способ, которым вы получаете `JAVA_HOME` в пакетных файлах и сценариях оболочки, следует точно такому же синтаксису, который используется командой `echo`.  Закройте переменную знаком процента и используйте эту переменную в своем коде так же, как и любую другую переменную в сценарии.
>
> Сценарии, использующие `JAVA_HOME`, всегда следует проверять, существует ли эта переменная.  В противном случае появится соответствующее сообщение об ошибке.  Вот как проект Apache Maven получает `JAVA_HOME` в своем сценарии запуска mvn и сообщает обо всех ошибках во время процесса:

```
@REM Apache Maven JAVA_HOME Startup Script
@REM ==START JAVA_HOME VALIDATION ==
if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto OkJHome
for %%i in (java.exe) do set "JAVACMD=%%~$PATH:i"
goto checkJCmd

:OkJHome
set "JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

:checkJCmd
if exist "%JAVACMD%" goto chkMHome

echo JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly >&2
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program >&2
echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE >&2
goto error
```